# spinner is not showing after 2000ms

Tags: angular, angular-material

want to show the spinner after the form submission for 2000 ms for that I have implemented set timeout function but it is not going inside that function even after 2000ms.
below my code snippet of component and html

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../../shared/services/data.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dummy',
  templateUrl: './dummy.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dummy.component.scss']
})
export class DummyComponent implements OnInit {
  loading= false;
  users= [];
  pinId;
  name: string;
  constructor(private router: Router, private dataService: DataService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  submit(name) {
  this.loading = true;
 this.dataService.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
     this.users = data;
     console.log(this.users);
this.users.forEach(element => {
  console.log(element);
  if (element.name === this.name) {
    this.pinId = element.pinId;
    console.log(this.pinId);
setTimeout(function() {
console.log(this.pinId);
                        if (this.pinId) {
                          this.loading = false;
                          this.router.navigate(['schedule']);
                        }
                      }, 2000);
  }
});
   }, error => {
     console.log('error');
   });

}


}
```

```html
<mat-card>
<div class="example-container">
  <mat-form-field color="accent">
    <input matInput placeholder="Input" [(ngModel)]="name">
  </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="submit(name)">Submit</button>
<mat-spinner *ngIf="loading"  color="accent"></mat-spinner>
</div>
</mat-card>
```

I want to show  the spinner after the form submission for 2000 ms for that I have implemented set timeout function but it is not going inside that function even after 2000ms.

Comment: use arrow function `setTimeout(() => {` instead of `setTimeout(function() {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In typescript function key word will not work

```
setTimeout(()=> {
console.log(this.pinId);
                        if (this.pinId) {
                          this.loading = false;
                          this.router.navigate(['schedule']);
                        }
                      }, 2000);
```